# How to evaluate a Dell HW-level RAID array status?

Tags: dell, ssd, raid

O/S: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

I have a Dell PowerEdge R440 with a RAID controller that has been configured with a bunch of SSD drives on it. The RAID-5 array was set up at hardware level before Ubuntu was installed. I've been trying to figure out a way to examine the RAID array and have it show me the status of the array using LINUX commands, without having to boot to the BIOS. But I can't seem to find a simple screen that would tell me Disk X has failed and Disk Y is a hot spare, etc.

I tried using smartctl from the smartmontools package. It gives me details, but I have not figured out a way to get a simple summary showing all the disks and the current status for each one. Is there a combination of flags or options that would give me such a summary?

These commands worked so far for me:

```
# smartctl --scan
/dev/sda -d scsi # /dev/sda, SCSI device
/dev/sdb -d scsi # /dev/sdb, SCSI device
/dev/bus/0 -d megaraid,0 # /dev/bus/0 [megaraid_disk_00], SCSI device
/dev/bus/0 -d megaraid,1 # /dev/bus/0 [megaraid_disk_01], SCSI device
/dev/bus/0 -d megaraid,2 # /dev/bus/0 [megaraid_disk_02], SCSI device
/dev/bus/0 -d megaraid,3 # /dev/bus/0 [megaraid_disk_03], SCSI device
/dev/bus/0 -d megaraid,4 # /dev/bus/0 [megaraid_disk_04], SCSI device
/dev/bus/0 -d megaraid,5 # /dev/bus/0 [megaraid_disk_05], SCSI device
/dev/bus/0 -d megaraid,6 # /dev/bus/0 [megaraid_disk_06], SCSI device
/dev/bus/0 -d megaraid,7 # /dev/bus/0 [megaraid_disk_07], SCSI device
```

These smartctl commands also work for me but I'm swamped with data that I'm not sure how to read:

```
# smartctl --all -d megaraid,1 /dev/sdb
# smartctl --xall -d megaraid,1 /dev/sdb
```

My background is with IBM AIX systems, and they have a handy diagnostics utility that can show you the status of a RAID array in a simple screen like this one:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
Name      Resource  State       Description              Size
------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
hdisk3    FC0100FF  Optimal     4K RAID 5 Array         1552GB  pdisk6
          000C08FF  Active      4K SSD Array Member        N/A  pdisk7  
          000C09FF  Active      4K SSD Array Member        N/A  pdisk8  
          000C0AFF  Active      4K SSD Array Member        N/A  pdisk9  
          000C0BFF  Active      4K SSD Array Member        N/A  pdisk10 
          000C0CFF  Active      4K SSD Array Member        N/A   
hdisk4    FC0200FF  Optimal     4K RAID 10 Array        1143GB  pdisk0  
          000C06FF  Active      4K Array Member            N/A  pdisk1  
          000C07FF  Active      4K Array Member            N/A
```

Is there some utility or tool that is available in Ubuntu that would be able to give a similar simple status report? The smartctl does not seem to give that (possibly because the devices don't support it?), when just asking for a health check:

```
# smartctl --health -d megaraid,1 /dev/sdb
smartctl 6.6 2016-05-31 r4324 [x86_64-linux-4.15.0-39-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART Status not supported: ATA return descriptor not supported by controller fi
rmware
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED
Warning: This result is based on an Attribute check.
```

Or is the "PASSED" message shown above ultimately what I'm looking for?

Thanks for any advice.

Steve N.

Comment: I used to like HDSentinel for that exact reason (it provided a summary of the detail obtained by `smartctl`). It's summary was a % of optimum speed, % of health & estimated-days-before-failure.  The program however is 'non-free' (*debian use of term*) and the no-cost version doesn't have the full features of the paid version.  If your machine is not a server (ie. has a gui) there are a number of gui tools that provide easier output.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. They have a trial version for download, so may take a look at that. Or I may have to script my own to collect the key values from smartctl. Just surprised Ubuntu does not have more tools for hardware monitoring, especially the hard disks and RAIDs. I also downloaded a DELL proprietary package called PERCCLI to give it a try. Just not sure all my Ubuntu servers will always be Dell.